# free-jqgrid pre-defined currency formatter mod

Tags: formatting, currency, free-jqgrid

I am using free-jqgrid 4.15.6.
I am using built-in currency formatter which formats numbers perfectly.
I am using prefix:'$',defaultValue:'' in formatoptions.

When grid first loads, the rows whose currency columns are empty show no formatting in grid as should be.

But after inline editing, when nothing has been entered into edit control (meaning the control has no value entered), after editing, the pre-defined formatter displays '$' in the cell, rather than blank as desired.

Looking into the source free-jqgrid codebase, I see this function is being used to set formatted display:

```
   var insertPrefixAndSuffix = function (sOutput, opts) {
    // Prepend prefix
    sOutput = (opts.prefix) ? opts.prefix + sOutput : sOutput;
    // Append suffix
    return (opts.suffix) ? sOutput + opts.suffix : sOutput;
},
```

I have added a conditional test at beginning of this function that forces jqgrid to NOT format with currency options if the value to be formatted is an empty string.

```
var insertPrefixAndSuffix = function (sOutput, opts) {

    // return empty string if no cellvalue
    if(sOutput == '') { return ''; }

    // Prepend prefix
    sOutput = (opts.prefix) ? opts.prefix + sOutput : sOutput;
    // Append suffix
    return (opts.suffix) ? sOutput + opts.suffix : sOutput;
},
```

However, this edit, while it works for me is NOT the correct way to get this job done.  I know I should instead be extending the jqGrid pre-defined currenct formatter object, or maybe even the jQuery formatter object, but all my efforts have failed.

Can someone please tell me how to add this conditional code logic so that I can keep the free-jqgrid source unmodified but override the pre-defined currency formatter of the jqgrid?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to define your own custom formatter, rather than to extend the existing one. Definition of custom formatter in [Guriddo jqGrid is described here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#custom-formatter)

It should be similar in free-jqGrid.

Important note here is that you will need to define a custom **unformat** function too. Just look into the docs provided.

[Here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#example-formatter) you can see exactly your case.

Comment: Thank you @tony-tomov.  I just figured it best to use the pre-defined currency formatter since it does work well--adhering to locales.  It would be nice if there was a way to hook into the pre-defined version and have it ignore blank values thus skipping the application of formatting to them.  But knowing you are the primary reason that jqGrid even exists, I will take your advice.  Thanks again!